# Is a constant function (in complex analysis) entire?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I have been confused with this for quite some time, and hope someone could clarify with me. I have been doing questions that needs to use Cauchy Integral Formula, and sometimes the $f(z)$ i use is a constant function, for example $f(z) = 4i$. However , in Cauchy's formula, we do need to check that $f$ is analytic everywhere and within the contour $C$, hence it is important for me to know if a constant function is indeed analytic.

For a fact, a constant function is infinitely differentiable and identically 0 thereafter.

Comment: Yes, a constant function is analytic on its domain of definition.

Comment: Yes, any function that is once compex-differentiable is analytic and, as implied by your last sentence, this is certainly true for a constant.

Comment: Maybe we have different definitions, but to me it seems that your last statement directly implies that the function is entire. The definition of an entire function is a function which is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Since you admit that your function is differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$, by definition you admit its entire.

Comment: If you have the least bit of doubt, why not verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it:

For $c \in \mathbb{C}$, the constant function $f(z) = c\,$ is represented by the everywhere convergent power series

$$c + 0z + 0z^2 + 0z^3 +\, ...$$